# Basic layout/navigation question for android development

Tags: android, layout, view, navigation

What is the best approach for navigating between "windows" in an android app?

I say "windows" because I dont the proper terminology in java. I just started.

Lets say the first screen the user sees is a username and password input with a button. On successful login, it shows a whole new "window" with relevant logged in information?

I attempted putting 2 EditTexts and a Button inside a view (using the Main.xml graphical layout tab[eclipse]) in main.xml, but it did not like that.

Comment: Those "windows" are called activities, and the best place to learn about it is the android developers site: http://developer.android.com/index.html. They have many examples and tutorials on what is and how to use each component. And without seeing your xml we will probably not be able to help you much...

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the responses! I wasn't sure how to respond to all of you so hopefully you see this. You guys have given me more than I thought I would get. What a great community!..and I'm sure I'll get the hang of this stackoverflow voting system thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a excerpt from the page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

**Activities**
    An activity represents a single screen with a user interface. For example, an email application might have one activity that shows a list of new emails, another activity to compose an email, and another activity for reading emails. Although the activities work together to form a cohesive user experience in the email application, each one is independent of the others. As such, a different application can start any one of these activities (if the email application allows it). For example, a camera application can start the activity in the email application that composes new mail, in order for the user to share a picture.

Here's an tutorial on how to switch between activities: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/

Don't for get to add every activity to AndroidManifest.xml!

Comment: Hey thanks for the tutorial link. I am adapting that tutorial to my current test application. I am confused on the Intent part. He has it working in an OnClick event. Mine needs to happen without that so I am not passing `view`. How do I get access to it? I guess I need to know what the current view is..for example [http://pastie.org/1868786](http://pastie.org/1868786)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider activities as being "windows" for android.

Create different layout XMLs for your different activities and on a button click from activity A start activity B and close A... to give an example:

```
// in activity A for the button click:

public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    activity.finish();
}






// in activity B you have:

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.B); //using your B.xml layout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android way of doing it is to use an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for each 'window', as you call them. You move between Activities by using startActivity().

You shouldn't have any problem putting 2 edittexts & a button inside an xml layout, so the problem you're having is probably related to something else. Have you checked the log output for errors? Something that gets a lot of newcomers is that you have to declare every Activity in your mainfest file, otherwise Android will not load it.

Answer (score 0):

The "windows" in Android are called Activities and you move between them with Intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GroupPickerActivity.this, SmsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to understand, I'd recommend going through some tutorials before diving right in.  For each "window" (called content views in android), there should be an underlying Activity.

The Labs taught [here](https://sites.google.com/site/androidappcourse/labs/lab-1) from a college course at Cal Poly SLO helped me get very familiar with Android quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> Intent intent = new Intent(this,
>   otherclassname.class);
>
> ```
>   intent.putExtra("userid", userfield);  //sends the userid
>
>   startActivity(intent);
> ```
>
> public void onCreate(Bundle
>   savedInstanceState)
>       {
>
> ```
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.showhistoricweek);
>
>
>     senduserid = getIntent().getIntExtra("userid", 0); //gets the userid
> ```